# How to handle a native OS (Ubuntu) file upload window in selenium webdriver with python?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, python

This is my first time here but I have already posted this question on SO. I keep getting solutions for Windows + Java and not for Linux or python for that matter.

I am using Selenium and Python to automate a file upload application for the past many hours but nothing helpful!

The HTML DOM structure for this file upload is an `input` tag with its type attribute `value = 'file'`. I know I can make use of the `send_keys`.

The problem is I am not supposed to use `send_keys()` (as per the question I am trying to solve). The assumption is there are other ways of doing it.

Can anyone suggest me alternative ways to upload the file? I do get solutions for windows but not for Linux(Ubuntu). I know there are applications/tools to automate GUI components like `AutoIt` but there is nothing for Linux close to `AutoIt`.

I can say I have done my homework to find a solution. Only after not finding anything useful, I am asking this question, please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I work with file uploads during a Webdriver test?](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12851/how-can-i-work-with-file-uploads-during-a-webdriver-test)

Comment: Did you get any solution for that.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the club, Praveen; your problem is a rite of passage for Selenium users.

Instead of trying to automate the file dialog, you may have better luck issuing the same HTTP request that your file upload form would have issued.  Issuing a POST request for a file upload is a little bit harder than a GET request because of the encoding issues, but I suspect you know where to look to find the appropriate Python API.

Another option is to use set_keys() to set the value of the relevant file `input` element, like this:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("file")
elem.send_keys("/tmp/temp.txt")
```

Comment: You are the first ray of hope I have found! Thanks for your reply. was eagerly waiting for it. Let me try your solution.. Will get back to you... Thanks agaain!!!

Comment: @Praveen See above for a second option.

Comment: @ user246: I am trying to solve a question which asks me NOT to use send_keys(). The question is quite sure that there is another option available. I wanted to share my approach that I was trying yesterday which actually is your suggestion. _Any file upload to a remote server is nothing but a POST request that we make to that server. In python, we have libraries like urllib and urllib2 which have ways to create a POST request and send it in a Request object. This object will contain the URL where I need to upload the file and the data which is the file itself. Is this approach correct?_

Comment: (Apologies for missing that part of the question.) Yes, that was what I meant.  You probably need to use multipart encoding.  Of course if there are any other fields in your form, you need to include them too.

Comment: Here's what I have written till now: `import urllib
import urllib2 url = "https://upload.backupgrid.net/add"
        values = {"file_path":"/home/pinku/Desktop/Test_Upload.odt"}
        data = urllib.urlencode(values)
        print data
        req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(req)`

Comment: Above code does not work yet. Here are my doubts 1)Once I reach the page where I see the file upload button, should I click it? I guess not. 2)How to encode the data (in this case the file to be uploaded)?. Please help me with the syntax 3) What should I do after the _response_ returned by urlopen?. I am sure I am in the right direction till now. Your suggestions appreciated.

Comment: 1) No, you should not.  2) and 3) See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10306/discussion-between-praveen-and-user246)