# How to automate a download popup in browsers other than firefox in linux and Mac?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For automating a download popup in Firefox, we use Firefox Profile and for other browsers I've used AutoIt. Is there any other way to work around it in windows? And coming to the main question, I've recently shifted to Ubuntu. So is there some sort of script or tool I can run to automate download popups in other browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java ROBOT class, to handle window. Following code may help you.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver) has a comprehensive list of solutions on downloading files using Selenium. I suppose most of them are Windows based solutions.

I recently saw this [link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-handle-a-native-os-ubuntu-file-upload-window-in-selenium-webdriver-with) where there was a discussion regarding handling Ubuntu's file dialog. Although reading through the link I'm not sure if any solution was ever reached.