# Selenium pratice help needed

Tags: automated-testing

For automating practice sites, and selenium real time projects codes I've used AutoIt. Is there any other way to work around it in windows?

Coming to the main question, I've recently shifted to Ubuntu, so is there some sort of script or tool I can run to automate download popups in other browsers?

Comment: Isn't this same as http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-automate-a-download-popup-in-browsers-other-than-firefox-in-linux-and-mac ?